# Ruby convert Hexadecimal to integer (16 bits signed)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a software for using a RFID reader with ruby on rails and, after open the socket and get the tags, I convert data to hexadecimal with:

```
    while line = s.gets
      puts line.unpack('H*').to_s
    end
```

Then I get "a55a0019833400393939393939303030303232**fd6f**02080d0a" for one tag.

The RFID reader user manual tells:

*Remark:RSSI express as complement code, total 16 bits，which is 10 times the real value. For example, the real value is -65.7dBm，then RSSI=fd6f*

I have found online calculators (mathsinfun and calc.penjee.com) where I am able to convert the fd6f in -675.

I would like to know how can I get this conversion in Ruby 2.3.1 to continue with my project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`s>` is the correct unpack symbol for a 16-bit unsigned big endian number, so:

```
"\xfd\x6f".unpack('s>')[0] / 10.0
```

Result is:

```
-65.7
```

Comment: Thank you very much